# Mesh Analysis has failed to solve this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, analysis, nodal-analysis

I built the following circuit in LTSpice and found each mesh currents to be (which also matches the answer sheet provided by my professor):

> **i1: 9A**
>   **i2: 8A**
>   **i3: 11A**
>   **i4: -6A**

However, I am unable to solve each mesh current using Mesh Analysis following the sign conventions.

Here's my approach:

> **Mesh 1: i1 = 9A
>
>   Mesh 2: R1*(i2 - i1) + i4*3 + R2*(i2 - i3) = 0
>
>   Supermesh: R2*(i3 - i2) + R3*i4 = 0
>
>   Also: i3 - i4 = 17  ===> i3 = 17 + i4**
>
> **where R1=6ohm;  R2=4ohm;  R3=2ohm**

If I substitute in mesh current from the spice simulation, the supermesh matches where Mesh 2 doesn't. However, I checked many online sites and followed the sign conventions, but I am not able to get it to work, where did I do wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok, there was an error in the original question, the current dependent voltage source has a gain of "-3*i4", not 3*i4.

After correcting the sign, the formula is solved as expected.

Comment: How did your LTspice simulation match the prof's answers then when you had the wrong circuit?

Comment: when the circuit matches the original drawing (with wrong 3*i4), the mesh current i2 was something like 43/7. After I put the minus sign fo (-3*i4), the mesh current i2 became 8A, and there was 6V across R1.